# How can I fix "You are running Vue in development mode" when building a Web Component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm building a Web Component with VueJS, for which is very hard to find documentation online, besides a couple blogs with basic examples, using the following command that I found in the CLI's help screen:

```
vue-cli-service build --mode production --target wc --name creador-publico src/views/CreadorPublico.vue
```

(I'm forcing mode to production even tho it supposedly defaults to production)

... But no matters what I do, I keep getting:

[image: error]

The command creates an HTML file and 2 JS, one minified and one not, and I have tried with both of them and got the same result.

I'd love to find good documentation for Vue web components, but it appears to be non existent.

Comment: How are you running the built application exactly? As in, if you import this component this component into a Vue application and run that application in production, non-development mode, do you get the same error? I ask because `vue-cli-service serve` runs applications in development mode by default. You can specify `mode` to ``vue-cli-service serve`` https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-serve

Comment: I want to put this component into a regular website, I will just include Vue with <script src..> so the component can run, but I'm even thinking of embedding Vue inside the component (option --inline-vue). I'm just using a regular web server to test the component (the build includes an HTML file which runs just fine)

Comment: You are building the component fine, I think the issue is with how you are "running" this component. That's why I was trying to get clarification on what steps you are taking to run the application containing this component.

Comment: The generated HTML includes Vue from unpkg, the instantiation of Vue is done inside the component, I guess using the "--mode production" arg should be enough to set that instantiation to prod mode, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

The message occurs based on how you are including Vue in the page, not because of anything in the web component itself.

When you build the web component with the --target wc option it creates a sample demo.html file that looks like this:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="path/to/my-element.js"></script>

<!-- use in plain HTML, or in any other framework -->
<my-element></my-element>
```

https://unpkg.com/vue points to a development build of Vue.

Changing this line to point to a minified version of Vue will remove this message from the console, e.g.:

https://unpkg.com/browse/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js

Answer (score 1):

Use `Vue.config.productionTip = false;` before your initial `new Vue` instantiation.

Comment: And where am I supposed to do that, since I don't have direct access to the Vue instantiation?